# Mysql Workbench and Xampp - Update : Mysql is broken :(((

Tags: mysql, xampp

This time I'm using Fedora17. I've already installed Mysql Workbench because I'm working with Eclipse in some projeects of my college.

As I know, i can't mix xampp and a previous mysql installation. So how can I use xampp in this situation ? Maybe I'm wrong.

EDIT: I installed Xampp. It didnt work, so I unistalled it.
Then when i'm in mysql workbench, all my db are gone :(

I tried to reinstall mysql workbench with no results.

The last thing that it says in terminal : `sudo systemctl status mysqld.service`
 ---> the result-->

```
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri, 21 Sep 2012 03:20:43 -0500; 4min 17s ago
 Process: 10397 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysqld-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Process: 10396 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 10379 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysqld-prepare-db-dir (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysqld.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont try and run both instance of mysql at the same time. This is not possible. Please run xampp/xampp-portcheck.exe before run the xampp instance of mysql to see if your existing version is taking the port value 3306. If it is the case xampp instance of mysql will not start.

Check the below link, it will give the full description with screenshot to work with Mysql workbench with xampp
http://interconnectit.com/764/using-mysql-workbench-with-xampp/

Comment: I'm not using windows :/ I'm in Fedora17. Actually xampp works fine, but when I try to access phpmyadmin it says that I need to check this file "httpd-xampp.conf".

Comment: now it seems to work fine. I had to restart my laptop, so then all errors are gone :)